# How to disable and enable layout according to sound play in android

Tags: android, android-layout, audio, soundpool

In my app I am playing sound if user press on layout. But the problem is if user press layout again and again. Sound repeating again and again. I want layout become disable if sound is playing and enable when sound finish. so that user able to play sound again when its finish.

Code-

```
public class Boy1 extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    private SoundPool soundPool;
    private int soundID;
    boolean loaded = false;
    private LinearLayout layout1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.boy);
        layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.layout1);
        layout1.setOnTouchListener(this);
        // Set the hardware buttons to control the music
        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        // Load the sound
        soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                    int status) {
                loaded = true;
            }
        });
        soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.test, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // Getting the user sound settings
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
            // Is the sound loaded already?
            if (loaded) {
                soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: no its the whole code.

Comment: I am using soundpool not media player as suggested by most of the people to use soundpool for small duration sounds.

Comment: do you know the duration of that audio sound?

Answer (score 0):

Maintain an **boolean** for sound is playing or not...and based on that disable or enable your Layout as follows...

```
if (isSoundPlaying) {
    layout1.setEnabled(false);
} else {
    layout1.setEnabled(true);
}
```

**Update:**

when sound start playing then write **layout1.setEnabled(false);** it will disable the layout. as I understand **soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);** start the sound laying then write...

```
soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
layout1.setEnabled(false);
```

And when sound playing stops then write which will enable the layout...

```
layout1.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I have to just add this? and where?

Comment: And where to add layout1.setEnabled(true); in my code?

Comment: When your sound stops playing...and you know better than me when it stops playing sound.

Comment: In my code there is no stop method. You can see in my above code. Its complete code.

Comment: I am not understanding I know how to enable layout but the problem is dont know where to enable it.

Comment: you can see my reputation.

Comment: I have seen...who did that is not fair person.

Comment: I'm trying...thats why I'm taking time.

Comment: Sorry, i can't make it.

Comment: hmmm...someone downvote me also thats very bad yarrr